# Shift points based on attribute (e.g. slope and aspect, preferably with QGIS)

Tags: qgis, translate

I'm trying to shift point coordinates "upwards" based on a slope/aspect raster that I have computed beforehand. Working preferably with QGIS, but other means (i.e. R/ArcGIS [Standard/Pro]) are also possible.

I've looked for transformations, but haven't figured out how I'd make it dependent on attributes in general (~ underlying raster cells, specifically slope/aspect in my case).

I.e. I have a point dataset with points "red" and "blue" (black circle in image) from which I'd like to generate a new point dataset (green circle in image) based on slope/aspect.

**red**:

- slope: 45° (steep *=> larger shift*)
- aspect: 0° (facing north *=> moving south (180°)*)

**blue**:

- slope: 10° (shallow *=> minor shift*)
- aspect: 90° facing east *=> moving west (270°)*

[image: sketch displaying the point shift I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: Yeah, first step would be adding slope and direction as attributes (`add raster value to points`), then you can go on.

Comment: @Erik thanks, getting the raster values as attributes is not the problem though. generating the new coordinates based on them I haven't figured out yet

Comment: @BERA no, I'd rather use continous values.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table

Comment: And provide a logic which the shift should follow? Also: Should the actual geometry be moved, or does a changed symbology suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use QGIS expressions with [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) (for visualization purpose only) or [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (for actual geometries) - [see here for more details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) about both options.

Use this expression, replacing `slope` and `aspect` with the names of your attribute fields:

```
project( 
    $geometry, 
    slope,
    radians (180+aspect)
)
```

*Red points shifted to the blue destination, including a coeficient of 2000 on line 3 for the distance:*

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, I'd give +2 if I could for even providing a solution for visualization only. That allows to quickly experiment with the coefficient to scale the distance of the shift without generating actual geometries on each iteration! Thank you.